# Redirecionar com .htaccess se url conter string

Tags: php, htaccess, angular

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação utilizando `Angular4` e `PHP`, para que a URL do Angular funcione, eu preciso utilizar uma determinada configuração em `.htaccess` para direcionar para o `index.html`, assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Até aqui, tudo funciona como deveria, consigo acessar e dar *refresh* em qualquer página sem problema algum. Porém, também desejo utilizar o sistema de rotas em `PHP`, sendo assim, preciso de outro tipo de configuração para direcionar as chamadas para o `index.php`, que está em outra pasta. O diretório do projeto está mais ou menos assim:

```
raiz
│ index.html
│ vendor.bundle.js    
| [outros arquivos .js]  
│
└─api
│  │ index.php
│  │ init.php
│  │
│  └─vendor
└─assets
└─[outros arquivos]
```

E esta é a configuração para fazer o sistema de rotas `PHP` funcionar:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . api/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

O problema é que eu não consigo fazer os dois funcionarem ao mesmo tempo. Ou funciona a rota em `Angular` ou em `PHP`, mas não os dois juntos.

As rotas em `PHP` precisam ser direcionadas para o arquivo `/api/index.php` somente quando eu chamar alguma url que contenha a string `/api/'alguma-coisa'`, ou seja, sempre terá o prefixo `/api/`.

Como possível corrigir este problema e utilizar os dois sistemas de rotas?

...ou, se houver uma outra solução, posso usar tranquilamente, desde que atinja o objetivo final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não possuo conhecimentos muito avançados em `.htaccess`, mas consegui resolver a questão alterando apenas 2 linhas. Removi `RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]` e movi esta parte `RewriteBase /` para o topo. Com um código final assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api 
    RewriteRule . api/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Porém vou deixar a questão ainda em aberto, caso alguém possua uma resposta melhor ou mais educacional acerca do assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Legal que vc resolveu, mas existe uma outra maneira que seria colocar outro .htaccess dentro de uma pasta "api/", e apontar a rota para ela, exemplo:

Imagine que vc tenha uma pasta: `/raiz/public/`
Então vc cria uma pasta: `/raiz/api/`

Coloca o `.htaccess` com a seguinte inscrição:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /raiz/public/$1
```

O exemplo a seguir iria chamar sua pasta pública toda vez que vc acessar o subdiretório api/`{aqui ele iria reescrever tudo que chegasse}`:

```
/api/alguma-coisa
```